# Parameterized UIButton action selector for method in another class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

This is largely a syntactical question. How does one set the UIButton action selector to call a method of a different class? I've done a #import of the class whose methods I need to call with the button and I have the following **partial** understanding of what the button code should look like:

```
    UIButton *btnSplash = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btnSplash.frame = CGRectMake(250, 270, 180, 30);
    [btnSplash setTitle:@"Menu" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnSplash addTarget:self action:@selector([CLASS METHOD:PARAMETER]) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:btnSplash];
```

However, I get the following errors:

> expected ':' before '[' token
>
> method name missing in @selector

The sample code I've seen in the reference library calls local methods, so I'm trying to generalize and my attempts have thus far been unfruitful.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A selector is a representation of a method name regardless of which classes or categories implement it.

Say you have a class called `AnotherClass` which implements the method `- (void)doSomething:(id)sender`. The corresponding selector is `doSomething:`, represented in code as `@selector(doSomething:)`. If you want the button action to invoke that method, you need to have an instance of `AnotherClass` — and it is this instance that is the action *target*, instead of `self`. Hence your code should have:

```
#import "AnotherClass.h"

AnotherClass *instanceOfAnotherClass;
// assign an instance to instanceOfAnotherClass

UIButton *btnSplash = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btnSplash.frame = CGRectMake(250, 270, 180, 30);
[btnSplash setTitle:@"Menu" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btnSplash addTarget:instanceOfAnotherClass
              action:@selector(doSomething:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self addSubview:btnSplash];
```

Comment: Excellent. Now the question is, how do I still send a parameter for the doSomething:? I tried a couple different ways and it did not like constants or variables after the colon.

Comment: @OldMcStopher In the Cocoa Touch target action pattern, an action must comply with a set of predefined signatures. You cannot add arbitrary parameters to it. Depending on your needs, one solution is to use the `tag` property of `UIView`.

Comment: @OldMcStopher See this reference for the list of predefined action signatures accepted by Cocoa Touch: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW44

Comment: If that's the case, I think I'll just create another method in the AnotherClass that passes the appropriate parameters. Then I can just do action:@selector(doSomethingWithParameters:)