# Simple @selector Syntax Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This seems to be the simplest of problems... yet I can't figure out what's syntactically incorrect with this snippet.

Running this:

`UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:appDelegate action:@selector(addImage:NO)];`

Returns:

`Expected '(' before ')' token`

I've looked it over hundreds of times, yet I can't find what's wrong with it. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parameterized UIButton action selector for method in another class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610523/parameterized-uibutton-action-selector-for-method-in-another-class)

Comment: "addImage:"  is a valid  argument to @selector().  "addImage:NO" isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have `NO` in your `@selector()` directive.

Be careful.  UI Actions selectors should have the method signature:

```
- (void)myMethod:(id)sender;
```

and not

```
- (void)myMethod:(BOOL)someBool;
```

You may need a wrapper method:

```
- (void)doneAction:(id)sender;
{
    [appDelegate addAction:NO];
}
```

Comment: Up voted for mentioning ":(id)sender" as method signature, totally forgot about it.

Comment: Actually, there are **three** possible signatures for actions in Cocoa Touch.

Answer (score 0):

@selector() can't accept default values, change it to

```
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:appDelegate action:@selector(addImage:)];
```

Edit:
To make things clear, when you have
- (void)addImage:(BOOL)resize;
this is translated to "addImage:" as "method" name (selector) and when you pass over "addImage:NO" you are telling objc to look
- (void)addImage:(BOOL)resize NO:(BOOL)nod; // just for the example
ending up with wrong (invalid) selector, resulting in double back trace to all super objects calling respondsToSelector(addImage:NO) then throwing BAD_ACCESS.

p.s. Its more then year since I wrote my last line of objc.

Edit 2:
You can use wrapper as mentioned above or UIBarButtonItem.tag property

```
cancelButton.tag = 1; // 1 indicating addImage:NO

- (void) addImage:(id)sender {
    UIBarButtonItem *button = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
    if (button.tag == 1) {
        // your value is NO
    } else {
        // your value is YES
    }
}
```

but I would not go with this anyway. :)

Comment: With that particular method, the BOOL parameter has to be set... is there no way to call it with the NO parameter with @selector?

Comment: It depends, you have .tag property on the button (its UInteger if I remember correctly), you can use it for this purpose, I will update my code with example. I am not aware of other ways but there might be.